Why does my code send 429 Quota Exceeds on Google Gemini API with generative UI?
This is my first trying the new Vercel's generative UI with AI SDK, I am using Google's Gemini AI with the gemini-1.5-pro-latest model, It worked flawlessly on my local but when deployed it returns this response:
responseBody: '{\n' +
'  "error": {\n' +
'    "code": 429,\n' +
'    "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",\n' +
'    "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"\n' +
'  }\n' +
'}\n',

I am using Next 14 with Typescript, so the function is on server side (copied from Vercel's documentation), here is the function to call the SDK:
export async function continueConversation(
  input: string
): Promise<ClientMessage> {
  "use server";

  const history = getMutableAIState();

  const result = await streamUI({
    model: google("models/gemini-1.5-pro-latest"),
    system: `
      You are a general purpose assistant, you can help the user with a variety of tasks. You can tell jokes, give place and song recommendations, and much more. You are a professional, don't use emote.
      `,
    messages: [...history.get(), { role: "user", content: input }],
    text: ({ content, done }) => {
      if (done) {
        history.done((messages: ServerMessage[]) => [
          ...messages,
          { role: "assistant", content },
        ]);
      }
      return (
        <article className="markdown-container">
          <Markdown remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm]}>{content}</Markdown>
        </article>
      );
    },
    tools: {
      getJoke: {
        description:
          "A tool when the user wants a joke. The joke should make the user laugh.",
        parameters: z.object({
          category: z.string().optional().describe("the category of the joke"),
        }),
        generate: async function* ({ category }) {
          yield <LoaderCircle />;
          const joke = await generateObject({
            model: google("models/gemini-1.5-pro-latest"),
            schema: jokeSchema,
            prompt:
              "Generate a joke that will make the user laugh. The joke should be in the category of " +
              category +
              ". If no category is provided, ask the user for a category.",
          });
          return <JokeComponent joke={joke.object} />;
        },
      },
      getPlaces: {
        description:
          "A tool when the user wants place recommendations based on the location and type.",
        parameters: z.object({
          location: z.string().describe("the user's location"),
          type: z.string().optional().describe("the type of place"),
        }),
        generate: async function* ({ location, type }) {
          yield <LoaderCircle className="loader-circle" />;
          const places = await generateObject({
            model: google("models/gemini-1.5-pro-latest"),
            schema: placeSchema,
            prompt:
              "Generate an array of places to visit in " +
              location +
              " with the type of " +
              (type || "any type") +
              ". The array should contain at least 5 places.",
          });
          if (places && places.object && Array.isArray(places.object)) {
            return <PlaceComponent place={places.object} />;
          } else {
            return <p>Something went wrong, please try again later.</p>;
          }
        },
      },
      getSongs: {
        description:
          "A tool when the user wants song recommendations based on the genre.",
        parameters: z.object({
          genre: z.string().optional().describe("the genre of the song"),
          singer: z.string().optional().describe("the singer of the song"),
        }),
        generate: async function* ({ genre, singer }) {
          yield <LoaderCircle />;
          const songs = await generateObject({
            model: google("models/gemini-1.5-pro-latest"),
            schema: songSchema,
            prompt:
              "Generate songs recommendation in the genre of " +
              (genre || "any genres") +
              "or by the singer " +
              (singer || "any singer") +
              ". Return an array of 3 songs.",
          });
          if (songs && songs.object && Array.isArray(songs.object)) {
            return <SongComponent song={songs.object} />;
          } else {
            return <p>Something went wrong, please try again later.</p>;
          }
        },
      },
    },
    
  });

  return {
    id: nanoid(),
    role: "assistant",
    display: result.value,
  };
}

Here is the full actions.tsx and page.tsx:

actions.tsx : https://github.com/msafdev/msaf.pr/blob/main/lib/actions.tsx
page : https://github.com/msafdev/msaf.pr/blob/main/app/page.tsx

I tried to change the API key with new accounts to no avail, the thing is, it still works on my local :< Any suggestions will be very appreciated, thanks!

Is there not a number in the response that says how much rate limit you have left or how long you should wait to send another request?

If you are seeing a 429 quota error, then you have run out of quota.
You can see the default quota here: https://ai.google.dev/pricing (make sure you choose the model you are using).
As you are using gemini-1.5-pro-latest, and I assume you're using the free tier, your quota would be 2 requests per minute (this was correct at the time of writing but check the pricing page). If you try a 2-turn request locally, and then deploy the same API key to another environment and run it within a minute, you won't have any remaining quota.
Try waiting a minute and see if the error persists. Otherwise try using a model with more quota, like gemini-1.5-flash-latest, or enable billing for much higher limits.

no, i use different account for both development and production, i also tried to wait for a minute or two then request another API call but it still gives that error

Thanks. I am using aider-chat, and I didn't realize pro latest was only 2 requests per minute. flash latest is the solution for me!

If you are using Gemini's Pro model, there are several limitations. I would suggest using Gemini's Flash models to avoid these limitations. While it also has some limitations, the Flash model is better compared to the Pro.
For deployment, you can consider the pay-as-you-go method to minimize these limitations.
